# Abstract int() causing an invisible halt in my application

Tags: java

I noticed today that a certain feature wasn't working at all in my API and it's actually devistating to the progress I'm making on my application that's using the API. There's absolutely no errors being produced, the application doesn't stop, hang, or even stutter. It justs acts as if I called `return` and carries on with it's processing.

The **in a nutshell** class:

```
public abstract class Foo {

    private static Foo singleton;

    public Foo() {
        singleton = this;
    }

    public static Foo getSingleton() { 
        return singleton;
    }

    public abstract int bar();
}
```

in which I have another class that inherits from this like so:

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar(...) {
        super...
    }

    @Override
    public int bar() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Now, the class "Bar" isn't in the same project as the "Foo" class, as the "Foo" class is part of an API (.jar) that is added as a dependency; However inside the .jar I have some code that needs to reference the value set by the overriden class over bar()

The code that I'm using that currently upsets my girlfriend is below:

```
int foo = Foo.getSingleton().bar(); // This should return the value of 5 set earlier
```

Which does not set the value of foo, and in-fact doesn't even print out to the console if I add a `System.out.println` after it. It literally just feels like it `return`'s

Comment: Does it throw a `NullPointerException`? Have you initialized `singleton`?

Comment: singleton is initialized, it does not throw an exception at all.

Comment: Please post a complete and reproducible example.

Comment: And please remove the unnecessary content which only makes the question longer to read

Comment: The example I posted is complete.

Comment: @Christian.tucker how can you return singleton in getSingleton() if it is not protected, but rather it is private?

Comment: why is the constructor of Foo (a singleton) public ?

Comment: @TheRedFox -- There is a getter.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see it was inside foo

Comment: @MihaiC - It's an example..

Comment: @Christian.tucker you should be getting a nullpointerexception. foo is null

Answer (score 2):

This constructor

```
private static Foo singleton;

public Foo() {
    singleton = this;
}
```

which initializes the `static` `singleton` field will only be invoked if you create a new instance of a subtype of `Foo`, ie. `Bar`.

You haven't showed a new instance creation expression involving `Bar`, so I assume there isn't one.

As such

```
int foo = Foo.getSingleton().bar(); // This should return the value of 5 set earlier
```

can only terminate with a `NullPointerException` when trying to invoke `bar()` on the `null` returned by `getSingleton()`.

If you aren't seeing the NPE, then you must be catching it and ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

Your singleton is not correctly implemented. `Foo.getSingleton()` will return `singleton` which is `null` at that point. The static variable is only initialized in the constructor which is never called in your example. You'll have to initialize `singleton` in a static context, e.g. inside your `getSingleton()` method with a null check:

```
public static Foo getSingleton() {
    if(singleton == null) {
        singleton = new Foo();
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

**EDIT**

As MihaiC correctly stated in the comments, this wouldn't work since `Foo` is abstract. I did miss that little detail. Considering this it really doesn't make sense to have a singleton of an abstract class, unless you try to somehow initialize it with a `Bar` instance. The design still feels strange to me. Still leave my answer above for now for the general concept.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue; However I agree that the implementation in the example I provided is incorrect. This is how the singleton is initiated inside of my code; However for the `post a short example` rule of thumb I removed it to clean it up. Regardless as if it is acting as a `singleton` or `instance` the value should still be returned.

Comment: @Christian.tucker your question should include a **working** minimal example. If you don't know what causes the problem, how can you know what details are irrelevant for it?

Comment: i thought the same thing @Christian.tucker you should at least try

Comment: @AndréStannek this won't even compile in his example, since foo is abstract :P

Comment: How do I give a runnable example of an issue that only occurs when the code is being referred to as a dependency. I would have to supply all of the code for the .jar, the .jar, and then the code that was built ontop of the jar. The example i provided is **Working** to reproduce the error, if you remove the dots, it will compile perfectly. Create a .jar from it, import the .jar into another project, then extend the Foo class, then try to access the foo() variable through the ""singleton""

Comment: @Christian.tucker in this case it means that you should post the code the same way that produces the error. Giving us an obviously non working piece of code of course makes us consider the obvious errors without assuming that you somehow did it right in your actual code.

Comment: @Christian.tucker yes it would still throw a NPE unless you create a Bar obj before calling Foo.getSingleton().bar(). the field singleton in Foo is static which means it gets loaded and initialized at class load (with default NULL). Since Foo is abstract you can't instantiate it, so you have to instantiate a Bar object. This would invoke the super constructor of Foo (since bar extends foo) so then Foo becomes Bar (singleton=this means basically Foo=Bar). Then running Foo.getSingleton().bar() will return 5 since your Foo instance is actually a Bar object; add: Bar a=new Bar(); before...